# Refactoring redux class based component into a functional component with hooks. Get an error about async actions. Why?

Tags: redux, oauth, oauth-2.0, react-redux, react-hooks

I am following a tutorial, where the teacher is using `react-redux` with classes. To understand it better, I decided to use hooks.

Unfortunatly I got stuck on a problem and am in need of your help.

The tutorial app uses oauth to signIn in gapi. For this a button is used, which, dependent on the authorization state show, that one can logIn or signOut. When signing in, one can choose in a popup window a google account.
But when I click on this button to logIn, I get an error, that says:

Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

1) But in my app I use the hook called `useEffect()` with .then to omit the use of middleware like `thunk`. Or am I wrong on that?

2) Should I be using `useEffect()` and `useDispatch()` in my app or can be everything done with `useSelector()` (or/and `useDispatch()`, or/and `useEffect()`)

3) The tutorial code uses `{ connect }` which is an equivalent of `useSelector()`. Am I not using unnecessary `useDispatch()` and/or `useEffect()`? If yes, than how could I change the text of the button without dispatch?

Here is the tutorial code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn, signOut } from '../actions';

class GoogleAuth extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
      window.gapi.client
        .init({
          clientId:
            '797401886567-9cumct9mrt3v2va409rasa7fa6fq02hh.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          scope: 'email'
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

          this.onAuthChange(this.auth.isSignedIn.get());
          this.auth.isSignedIn.listen(this.onAuthChange);
        });
    });
  }

  onAuthChange = isSignedIn => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      this.props.signIn(this.auth.currentUser.get().getId());
    } else {
      this.props.signOut();
    }
  };

  onSignInClick = () => {
    this.auth.signIn();
  };

  onSignOutClick = () => {
    this.auth.signOut();
  };

  renderAuthButton() {
    if (this.props.isSignedIn === null) {
      return null;
    } else if (this.props.isSignedIn) {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.onSignOutClick} className="ui red google button">
          <i className="google icon" />
          Sign Out
        </button>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.onSignInClick} className="ui red google button">
          <i className="google icon" />
          Sign In with Google
        </button>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderAuthButton()}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { signIn, signOut }
)(GoogleAuth);
```

---

And my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { signIn, signOut } from "../actions";

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

const GoogleAuth = () => {
    const isSignedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isSignedIn);
    console.log("IsSignedIn useSelector: " + isSignedIn);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const onAuthChange = () => {
                if (isSignedIn) {
                    dispatch(signIn(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getId()));
                } else {
                    dispatch(signOut());
                }
            };

            window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
                window.gapi.client
                    .init({
                        clientId: API_KEY,
                        scope: "email"
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        onAuthChange(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                        console.log("isSignedIn.get(): " + window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                        window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(onAuthChange);
                    });
            });
        },
        [ dispatch, isSignedIn ]
    );

    const onSignInOnClick = () => {
        dispatch(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn());
    };

    const onSignOutOnClick = () => {
        dispatch(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut());
    };

    const renderAuthButton = () => {
        if (isSignedIn === null) {
            return null;
        } else if (isSignedIn) {
            return (
                <button onClick={onSignOutOnClick} className="ui red google button">
                    <i className="google icon" />
                    Sign Out
                </button>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <button onClick={onSignInOnClick} className="ui red google button">
                    <i className="google icon" />
                    Sign In with Google
                </button>
            );
        }
    };

    return <div>{renderAuthButton()}</div>;
};

export default GoogleAuth;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error message:
**Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.**

That's right. Without middleware that can handle another type of action, that won't work.

**1) But in my app I use the hook called useEffect() with .then to omit the use of middleware like thunk. Or am I wrong on that?**

`useEffect` and `.then` aren't related to redux. You are wrong here. The actions you are using are the thunks (functions that return function(dispatch, getState)) and you definitely need a `redux-thunk`

**2) Should I be using useEffect() and useDispatch() in my app or can be everything done with useSelector() (or/and useDispatch(), or/and useEffect())**

You need `useEffect` to make a call to 3rd party API when component mounts.
You need `useDispatch` to get the `dispatch` function.
You need `useSelector` to get the value fro the redux-store.

**3) The tutorial code uses { connect } which is an equivalent of useSelector(). Am I not using unnecessary useDispatch() and/or useEffect()? If yes, than how could I change the text of the button without dispatch?**

The code: (can be broken)

```js
    const GoogleAuth = () => {
        const isSignedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isSignedIn);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();

        useEffect(
            () => {
                const onAuthChange = (isSignedInLocal) => {
                    if (isSignedInLocal) {
  dispatch(signIn(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getId()));
                    } else {
                        dispatch(signOut());
                    }
                };

                window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
                    window.gapi.client
                        .init({
                            clientId: API_KEY,
                            scope: "email"
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                            onAuthChange(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                            
                            window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(onAuthChange);
                        });
                });
            },
            [dispatch]
        );

        const onSignInOnClick = () => {
            dispatch(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn());
        };

        const onSignOutOnClick = () => {
            dispatch(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut());
        };

        const renderAuthButton = () => {
            if (isSignedIn === null) {
                return null;
            } else if (isSignedIn) {
                return (
                    <button onClick={onSignOutOnClick} className="ui red google button">
                        <i className="google icon" />
                        Sign Out
                    </button>
                );
            } else {
                return (
                    <button onClick={onSignInOnClick} className="ui red google button">
                        <i className="google icon" />
                        Sign In with Google
                    </button>
                );
            }
        };

        return <div>{renderAuthButton()}</div>;
    };

    export default GoogleAuth;
```

Make sure you don't provide `isSignedIn` as a dependency for `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

Redux has some specific use-cases and cons, but introduces some downsides like lots of boilerplate. Not knowing why you need redux is probably a sign you don't need redux.

However:
useState and useEffect are the two basic React primitives.
`[state, setState] = useState(initialState)` lets you use a state and set it;
`useEffect(callback, [deps])` fires a callback whenever one of the dependencies change.
You probably don't need anything else.

Redux uses a different approach:

1. It uses a single, centralized state for the whole app (that you can get in any component with the `useSelector()` hook
2. It lets you change it via plain javascript objects (like `{ type: 'SIGN_IN', payload: { token: '42' } }`), and define, for each of these objects, how the state should change (defining a so-called "reducer" function). You dispatch these state changes via the `dispatch()` function.

How about effects then?
Since dispatch only takes an object as argument (since the business logic is defined elsewhere), there's no point in passing to it a function or a promise.
But you can trigger them in several ways:

1. Directly in a callback, e.g. `<button onClick={() => auth.signIn()}> Sign in </button>`. That is absolutely fine.
2. Inside the useEffect hooks, if you need to trigger the effect as a reacion of a state change. E.g.: `` useEffect( () => console.log(`count changed, new value is: ${count}`), [count]) ``
3. Via redux middleware

Option 1 and 2 are perfectly fine, but the downside is that you have to define business logic locally, instead of decoupling it from the view.
Defining it in a different place lets you scale and mantain the app more easily.

Custom middleware enhances the way `dispatch()` works.
One of the simplest way is [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).
It lets you pass a callback to dispatch:

```js
// somewhere in the codebase:
function signIn(){
  window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()
}

...

// Inside you button:
<button onClick={() => dispatch(signIn())}> Sign Out </button>
```

There are more sofisticated effects model, but you can stick with redux-thunk unless you need something more powerful.

Just remember that each of these frameworks is just a tool with specific tradeoffs, and unless you *really* have a reason of using them, you can just stick with the excellent React primitives, instead of overengineering your app with no reason.